# Why Gmail mark as spam emails from my postfix server?

Tags: linux, postfix, spam, gmail

I'm trying to send email from postfix to different providers: Hotmail OK, Yahoo Not tested, Italian Provider OK, GMAIL KO !

I have SPF and rDNS set correctly ... this is the header:

```
Delivered-To: mymail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.182.122.34 with SMTP id lp2csp107348obb;
        Thu, 16 Aug 2012 10:28:50 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.216.198.145 with SMTP id v17mr1084539wen.1.1345138129729;
        Thu, 16 Aug 2012 10:28:49 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <sender@mydomain.it>
Received: from ispconfig.myserver.it (ispconfig.myserver.it. [*.*.*.*])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id a27si7050105wej.31.2012.08.16.10.28.48;
        Thu, 16 Aug 2012 10:28:49 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of sender@mydomain.it designates *.*.*.* as permitted sender) client-ip=*.*.*.*;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of sender@mydomain.it designates *.*.*.* as permitted sender) smtp.mail=sender@mydomain.it
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by ispconfig.myserver.it (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6A92076716
    for <mymail@gmail.com>; Thu, 16 Aug 2012 19:28:48 +0200 (CEST)
To: =?utf-8?B?U2VyZ2lvIEJlbGxpbmk=?= <mymail@gmail.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?TXVyYWxlc3RvcmUuaXQgLSBDb25mZXJtYSBsJ2FjY291bnQgU2VyZ2lvIEJlbGxpbmk=?=
From: Label <sender@mydomain.it>
Reply-To: Label <sender@mydomain.it>
Date: Thu, 16 Aug 2012 17:28:48 +0000
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126

Answer (score 1):

You should check your sending ip on `SenderScore` and check you mail with some spam score tools, also you can read `Bulk Senders Guidelines` written by Gmail. Almost forgot about `DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM)`.

Comment: if I send the same email with the smtp of my provider, that have no SPF and no DKIM, the email goes in Inbox ! :(

Comment: I think your ISP's smtp server has much more positive "history" than yours, you can check it on SenderScore project as I said.

Comment: senderscore says "Insufficient Email Seen" ... i can't use DKIM because my DNS doesn't configure the record :( there are alternatives ?

Comment: Just start sending and ask people to add you to contacts, maybe later your "trust" will grow.